How to use CDN to import package in Vite?
I'm developing a web project using Vite, Vue and Element-Plus. I found vite-plugin-cdn-import and try it, some js can success to download from CDN, while others can't work.
Using these package (package.json):
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "d3": "^4.5.0",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "save-svg-as-png": "^1.4.17",
    "vite-plugin-cdn-import": "^0.3.5",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  ...
}

How I use (App.vue):
import axios from 'axios'
import { ElMessage } from 'element-plus'
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import { utils, writeFile } from 'xlsx'
import { select } from 'd3'
import * as svg from 'save-svg-as-png'

How I use vite-plugin-cdn-import:
import importToCDN from 'vite-plugin-cdn-import'
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    importToCDN({
      modules: [
        {
          name: 'axios',
          var: 'axios',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/axios/1.5.0/axios.min.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'xlsx',
          var: 'xlsx',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.5/cpexcel.min.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'jquery',
          var: '$',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'd3',
          var: 'd3',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'save-svg-as-png',
          var: 'saveSvgAsPng',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/save-svg-as-png/1.4.17/saveSvgAsPng.min.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'vue',
          var: 'vue',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/axios/1.5.0/axios.min.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'element-plus',
          var: 'ElementPlus',
          path: 'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/element-plus/2.3.7/index.full.min.js'
        },
      ]
    })
  ]
})

Only axios, jquery, d3 can work well, others will report errors.
I init a new Vue project to try import vue from CDN, it reports importToCDN is not a function.
How can I import every package using CDN? Does it depend on how the package export the modules? Actually I don't very know how to write modules of vite-plugin-cdn-import, what should I fill in name and var?
Thx!

vite-plugin-cdn-import
How to use CDN


Before moving libraries to a CDN, you need to make sure that they are available in a format suitable for use via a CDN.
Check them on Unpkg and jsDelivr
